# min-max algorithm

Tags: c#, multithreading, chess, minmax

I have written a single-threaded min-max algorithm for a chess game that works fine. Now I am trying to rewrite it to use all avaliable cpu-cores, but I can not get it to work correctly.

My idea is to spawn as many threads as there are cores on the system (in my case 4) and to let the threads add and remove work items from a queue. Each of these work items is a "CalculateState" that holds information about a possible chessboard after x number of moves on the board.

When a workitem is spawned at maxDepth it will evaluate the chessboard and "return" its value. The return is done by propegating its value upwards in the tree of examined moves (to simulate recursion).

Algorithm start:

```
private readonly ConcurrentPriorityQueue<int, CalculateState> _calculateStates = new ConcurrentPriorityQueue<int, CalculateState>(); 
private Thread[] _threads = new Thread[Environment.ProcessorCount];
private const int MaxDepth = 3;
private PlayerColor _maxPlayer;

public Move CalculateMoveMultithreaded(ChessBoard board)
    {
        _maxPlayer = board.TurnToMove;
        var parentState = new CalculateState(null, null, 0, null, int.MaxValue, int.MinValue, board.TurnToMove);

        foreach (var move in board.GetPossibleMoves())
        {
            move.MakeMove(board);
            var newState = ChessStateTransforms.TransformChessBoardToState(board);
            move.UnMakeMove(board);

            _calculateStates.Enqueue(MaxDepth, new CalculateState(move, newState, 1, parentState, int.MaxValue, int.MinValue, Player.OppositeColor(board.TurnToMove)));
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < _threads.Length; i++)
        {
            var calculationThread = new Thread(DoWork);
            _threads[i] = calculationThread;
            calculationThread.Start();
        }

        foreach (var thread in _threads)
        {
            thread.Join();
        }

        return parentState.MoveToMake;
    }
```

Thread execution:

```
private void DoWork()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            KeyValuePair<int, CalculateState> queueItem;
            if (!_calculateStates.TryDequeue(out queueItem))
                break;

            var calculateState = queueItem.Value;
            var board = ChessStateTransforms.TransformChessStateIntoChessBoard(calculateState.ChessState);

            if (calculateState.Depth == MaxDepth)
            {
                var boardValue = board.ValueOfBoard(_maxPlayer);
                calculateState.PropergateValue(boardValue);
                continue;
            }

            foreach (var move in board.GetPossibleMoves())
            {
                move.MakeMove(board);
                var newState = ChessStateTransforms.TransformChessBoardToState(board);
                move.UnMakeMove(board);

                _calculateStates.Enqueue(MaxDepth - calculateState.Depth, new CalculateState(calculateState.MoveToMake, newState, calculateState.Depth + 1, calculateState, calculateState.MinValue, calculateState.MaxValue, Player.OppositeColor(board.TurnToMove)));
            }

        }
    }
```

Work item context.

```
 private class CalculateState
    {
        public readonly PlayerColor Turn;
        public int MaxValue;
        public int MinValue;

        public readonly int Depth;
        public readonly ChessState ChessState;
        public Move MoveToMake;

        private readonly CalculateState _parentState;        

        public CalculateState(Move moveToMake, ChessState chessState, int depth, CalculateState parentState, int minValue, int maxValue, PlayerColor turn)
        {
            Depth = depth;
            _parentState = parentState;
            MoveToMake = moveToMake;
            ChessState = chessState;
            MaxValue = maxValue;
            Turn = turn;
            MinValue = minValue;
        }

        public void PropergateValue(int value, Move firstMove = null)
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                if (Turn == _maxPlayer)
                {
                    if (value > MaxValue)
                    {
                        MaxValue = value;

                        if (Depth == 0)
                        {
                            MoveToMake = firstMove;
                            return;
                        }

                        _parentState.PropergateValue(MaxValue, MoveToMake);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (value < MinValue)
                    {
                        MinValue = value;

                        if (Depth == 0)
                        {
                            MoveToMake = firstMove;
                            return;
                        }

                        _parentState.PropergateValue(MinValue, MoveToMake);
                    }


                }
            }
        }
}
```

As it is the algorithm will return moves that takes the enemies pieces, but does not protect its own at all.
I am confident that the code in chessboard, move, valueofboard etc is correct. The problem must like in the multithreading/propegate value code. I have torn my hair over this for over a week and would really appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: What's the problem exactly? What isn't working as it should?

Comment: The min-max does not work. For example it will take my Rock even if it looses its Queen in the process.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for not giving the exact answer on what you've asked (actualy your problem isn't clear ebough and investigating that based on what you've given is very hard), but I recommend better implementing **alpha-beta pruning** in your min-max. It may help you much more than hundreds of CPU-cores. It you like to read about that, see http://www.cs.utah.edu/~hal/courses/2009S_AI/Walkthrough/AlphaBeta/ and http://cs.ucla.edu/~rosen/161/notes/alphabeta.html

PS: regarding your question it would be hard to implement recursion multithreaded (effectively using all threads and not splitting the move-tree only on top-level). I'm almost sure you've done a bug there. I'd recommend you using additional queue of states needed to calculate (expand). Every thread should get item from the queue and calculate it adding clild nodes to your tree. So your algorithm will not be DFS any more but will transform into BFS (breadth first search) which is much more effective in such move-calculation tasks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have used alpa-beta pruning in my single threaded version and planned to implement something similar for the multithreaded as well, but I need it to work first. I realize that the question is not easy to investigate. I would be very happy to see code/psudocode of a working version instead of a bugfix of my own.